# Procedures on Free Pascal

Tags: pascal, lazarus, freepascal

Im relatively new to Pascal and, though i have a fair understanding of the language, there's still some stuff i cant figure out how to implement. I've ran into this problem and, after trying for like hours on my own and looking for similar cases on the internet, i have not found anything. I hope this question is a fair one because, honestly, i dont know how to figure this out.

Here's the thing.

I have an application which dynamically creates TextBoxes (TextEdits in this case) and adds them to a panel for displaying. Thing is, i need to execute some procedures on the newly created elements. I added a new procedure in my app (this is for explaining purposes only):

```
procedure Demo_Procedure(i: integer, a: String);
```

Then i proceeded to "develop" my procedure underneath the "implementation" part of the Form.

```
procedure Demo_Procedure(i: integer, a: String);
begin
      ShowMessage(a, '  ' ,i);
end;
```

Now, for my dynamically created elements im trying to set the "OnKeyDow" event to run my new procedure (this is what i dont A- know if its possible to do or B- how to do it)

```
NewlyButton.OnClick:= Demo_Procedure(5, 'Hi');
```

Im getting different errors depending on how i call up my procedure. For example:

If i do it like this: Demo_Procedures(5, 'Hi'), it says:

> Error: Incompatible types: got "untyped" expected "procedure variable type of procedure(TObject,var Word,TShiftState) of object;Register>"

Now, researching around i found out that some people that put an '@' before calling the method, the only difference is that this time instead of saying "untyped" it says that it got "*procedure variable type of procedure(AnsiString,LongInt) of object*" and that it was expecting the same as before (*procedure(TObject,var> Word,Tshift...etc*)

Can anyone help me out here? I really am lost so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can only assign a 'method', a procedure of an 'object'. See [methods](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse30.html#refsu26.html).

Comment: In Object Pascal there is no built-in language construct available which would allow simple creation of `lambda` functions which in turn might be used as 1st class citizens together with other `... of object` functions. The thing you are trying to grasp is probably [GoF Command pattern](http://delphipatterns.blog.com/2011/03/28/command/)

Answer (score 3):

There are errors in your code:

```
procedure Demo_Procedure(i: integer, a: String); // Wrong
procedure Demo_Procedure(i: integer; a: String); // Right, use semicolon as parameters delimiter

ShowMessage(a, '  ' ,i); // Wrong, ShowMessage takes only one string parameter
ShowMessage(Format('%s  %d', [a, i])); // Right, %s means string value and %d means decimal value, see help about Format function
```

Events is a procedural variables so they have its own types. For example, `OnKeyDown` event have a type

```
TKeyEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState) of Object;
```

where `of Object` means that your event handler must be a class method.
So, you can not assign to the event any procedure but only class method with parameters provided in the type declaration.

Here is the simple code:

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
    Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type

    { TForm1 }

    TForm1 = class(TForm)
        Button1: TButton;
        procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
        procedure EditKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
    private
    public
        { public declarations }
    end;

var
    Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    e: TEdit;
begin
    e := TEdit.Create(Self); // Create new TEdit control
    e.Parent := Self; // Place control onto the form 
    e.Left := 10; // Set control coordinates
    e.Top := 10;
    e.OnKeyDown := @EditKeyDown; // Assign event handler
end;

procedure TForm1.EditKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
    ShowMessage(Format('Key code is %d', [Key]));
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! So there is not way to execute a procedure with my own parameters on a control's events like OnKeyDown, or OnClick? Sorry if i sound dumb, just new to Pascal :/

Comment: @OscarValdezEsquea Just replace `ShowMessage(Format('Key code is %d', [Key]));` by your procedure call. `Demo_Procedure(5, 'Hi');` in your example